# Как отредактировать код функции на повторение?

Tags: javascript, css3

Есть код, который заставляет текст плавно исчезать/появляться при скролле вниз/вверх. Как добиться многоразового повторения эффекта для каждого элемента, но не раньше появления на экране?(пока эффект срабатывая на первый элемент применяется сразу ко всем элементам с классом .text) я пока не знаю JS, так что пардон за глупый вопрос.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".text").css("opacity", (150 - height) / 100);
});
```

Comment: Какое конкретно ожидается поведение? Текст который по центру экрана должен быть полностью виден, а к краям размываться?

Comment: текст должен примерно с середины экрана исчезать,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно еще учитывать позицию каждого элемента относительно документа

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(".text").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.css("opacity", (el.offset().top - height - 20) / 100);
  });
});
```

```css
.text {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ffeaea;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Text1</div>
<div class="text">Text2</div>
<div class="text">Text3</div>
<div class="text">Text4</div>
<div class="text">Text5</div>
<div class="text">Text6</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду реализовывать)

Comment: @AntonTravnikov Если мой ответ решил Вашу задачу, отметьте его как верный